Signal fusion between different sensors
I have a 30-year time series of variable (soil water content at three depths) constrained between maximum and minimum values. During this period, three different types of sensors were used to record measurements at three distinct times. The problem is, I want to determine if the mean of the signal is changing over time, but each sensor measures a different range (max/min), causing artificial changes in the time series when the sensor switches (see plot below). To test if the signal is changing, I need to concatenate the three signals into a single, continuous time series. So far, I've tried standardizing each signal's output by its maximum measurement; however, I'm concerned this is forcing the mean of the time series to be stationary, which I suspect it is not.
Can anyone help me with ideas on how to approach this problem of signal fusion?


You don't have adequate data to do this without making some assumptions.  (For this reason, people who have experienced this problem--it happens all the time when changing analytical laboratories in monitoring programs--learn to overlap the monitoring when changing over.)  Regardless, using maxima for standardization is about the worst possible choice, because maxima are about as variable as possible.  Have you considered fitting a changepoint model with specified changepoints?  It looks like you need to accommodate simultaneous changes in conditional variance along with changes in trend.

Overlapping the monitoring would have been a good idea. I'll check if any procedure was followed when the sensors were switched. Regarding the second half of your answer, the maxima in this case is not highly variable because soil moisture is a bounded variable. It cannot exceed the point of saturation, which occurs during heavy rain events, thus is well-defined. Conversely, its minimum value is 0, but this condition is never actually achieved in reality. Does this information change your answer at all?

I had suspected that about the maximum, and it helps, but it raises a thorny question: exactly how would one sensor differ from another?  It's not going to be a simple change of location (where one sensor differs from the other by an additive constant).  If I were investigating this, I would want to learn as much as possible about how these sensors work and how they are calibrated so that I could formulate a reasonable mathematical model to relate one sensor's value to another's.  That would ground the statistical analysis in some supportable physical assumptions.

Thank you for your insight. If conditions are getting drier in this region, I might anticipate observing faster or more prolonged dry periods between storm events. Perhaps it is possible to assess dry-down speed by examining how rapidly the relative signal decreases following heavy storms. Consulting the user manuals of each sensor to explore potential mathematical relationships between their raw signals would be beneficial for detecting variations in dry-down magnitude.
